# Area between $y= \cos x$ and $y=\sin 2x$ on $[0,\pi/2]$

Tags: calculus, integration

I have no idea how to do this one, they intercept at some random point that I can not calculate.

$y= \cos x$, $y=\sin 2x$, $x= 0$ and $x= \pi/2$

I know the graph will go from $0$ to $0$ for $\sin 2x$ and then $1$ to $0$ for $\cos x$ so there are two areas I have to compute but I have no idea how to figure out the bounds on them.

Comment: Which area are you after? Can you clarify your question? [Check the graph](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5B%7BCos%5Bx%5D%2CSin%5B2*x%5D%7D)

Comment: use $\sin(2x) = 2\cos(x)\sin(x)$ to help you find that point.

Comment: @user13655: It's clear to me the question wants the absolute area between the two curves between $x=0$ and $=\pi/2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewriting 
$$\sin 2x = \sin x \cos x + \cos x \sin x = 2\sin x\cos x$$
we can compute the intersection: $\cos x = \sin(2x)$ is the same as
$$\begin{align*}
\cos x&= 2\sin x\cos x\\
\cos x - 2\sin x\cos x &= 0\\
\cos x(1 - 2\sin x) &= 0.
\end{align*}$$
The product is zero if and only if $\cos x = 0$ (which on $[0,\pi/2]$ occurs only at $x=\pi/2$), or if $1-2\sin x = 0$, which is the same as $2\sin x = 1$, which is the same as $\sin x = \frac{1}{2}$; on $[0,\pi/2]$, this happens once and only once: at $x=\pi/6$.

So the point of intersection is at $x=\pi/6$.

On $[0,\pi/6]$, we have that $\cos(x)$ is greater than $\sin(2x)$. On $[\pi/6,\pi/2]$, we have that $\sin(2x)$ is greater than $\cos x$. So the area is given by
$$\begin{align*}
\text{Area} &= \int_0^{\pi/2}|\cos x-\sin(2x)|\,dx\\
&= \int_0^{\pi/6}|\cos x - \sin(2x)|\,dx + \int_{\pi/6}^{\pi/2} |\cos x - \sin(2x)|\,dx\\
&= \int_0^{\pi/6}(\cos x - \sin (2x))\,dx + \int_{\pi/6}^{\pi/2}(\sin(2x) - \cos x)\,dx.
\end{align*}$$
Now you can simply compute the integrals and add up the appropriate quantities.

Comment: I am getting 2 as the answer but it is not the correct answer and I am not sure why.

Comment: Neither am I, since you don't say how you got the answer. As I tell my students, the Government doesn't let me read minds without a warrant.

Comment: cosx - sin2x for pi/6 - 0 = -1   and then sin2x - cosx for pi/2 - pi/6 = 0

Comment: Wrong, and wrong. You can't get a negative number for the first integral: you are integrating a **positive function**. You can't get $0$ for the second integral: You are integrating a **positive function**. And $-1$ and $0$ don't add up to $2$, so how could you possibly be getting 2 as the answer? Of course, since you continue to only give answers and not explain  your process, I cannot tell you *why* you are wrong, just that you are *definitely* wrong.

Comment: Break them up. Do the integral of $\cos x$ (you know the antiderivative, right?) Do the integral of $\sin(2x)$ (what is the antiderivative?) You'll have four integrals: two should be *immediate* (the ones with $\cos x$), two should be easy (a simple substitution).

Comment: I can't figure out what I am doing wrong but I get the idea of how to do this. I have spent far too long on this problem and I still have over 100 more to do. Thanks for the help.

Comment: And since you don't say *what* you did, nobody will be able to tell you what you did wrong. I'm sure it's Stewart's fault, too. If I had to bet, I probably would put my money on you getting the integral of  $\sin(2x)$ wrong.

Comment: I got $\frac {-1}{2} cos2x$

Comment: So I would lose my bet. I'm tired of guessing, though, and *I* know the right answer. Since you're not interested in knowing why you are wrong, that's it.

Comment: Thank you, I do appreciate the help I just do not have time to figure out the simple stuff I am getting wrong.